# What tool is a 'murphy bar'?

Tags: hand-tools

What is a 'murphy bar'?

Googling it, I found it mainly as a drinking bar; a liquor cabinet that folds down, like a Murphy bed.

Is it just a generic (dis-used?) term for prying under something to move it? I've heard tell of crow-bar like tools with wheels on them for this purpose and I'd swear I've seen them in catalogs. Am I using the wrong name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a long wooden bar, about 5' long, about 2" round at the top, tapering larger to about 6"x2" oval at the bottom, with (usually) steel wheels, and a steel "lever" at the bottom. Kind of like the design of a hand-truck.

It's used for moving or shifting heavy items.

I agree, images are impossible to find.

Edit: Found one:

[image: Pulled from Granger.com]

Search for "Pry Bar Lever Dollies" and you'll get all the Murphy bars you can handle. lol